# Inner join and left join not working as expected in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
table_supplier_bills - bill_id, supplier_id, date
table_supplier_bill_details - bill_id, product_id, quantity, rate
table_supplier_bill_payment_details - id, bill_id, payment_date, amount
```

I want to get all the bills with their bill_amount and paid_amount.

This is my query.

```
select 
SB.bill_id, 
SB.date, SB.supplier_id, 
SUM(SBD.quantity * SBD.rate) as bill_amount, 
COALESCE(SUM(SBPD.payment_amount), 0.00) as paid_amount 
from table_supplier_bills SB 
INNER JOIN 
table_supplier_bill_details SBD 
ON SB.bill_id = SBD.bill_id 
LEFT JOIN table_supplier_bill_payment_details SBPD 
ON SBD.bill_id = SBPD.bill_id 
group by SBD.bill_id;
```

But this query doesn't give correct paid_amount if there are multiple rows in table_supplier_bill_details for a bill. in case of multiple rows query gives the paid_amount multiplied by as many rows are in table_supplier_bill_details for that table.

Can anyone help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated query instead :

```
SELECT SB.bill_id, 
       SB.date,
       SB.supplier_id, 
       SUM(SBD.quantity * SBD.rate) as bill_amount, 
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(SBPD.payment_amount)
                 FROM table_supplier_bill_payment_details SBPD 
                 WHERE SBD.bill_id = SBPD.bill_id ),0.00) as paid_amount 
FROM table_supplier_bills SB 
INNER JOIN table_supplier_bill_details SBD 
 ON SB.bill_id = SBD.bill_id
GROUP BY SBD.bill_id;
```

Comment: This is working as expected. Can you please add some comments why query in question not working? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you already know why it's not working.. when using aggregation functions on a query with joins on 1*n relations, the records are being multiplied and therefore outputs wrong data. Better to use correlated queries / sum the data before the join.